# How to write data to prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have nginx log file on my server.the log file contain the http_duration of all request.
How can I write all of these http_duration data to promethues?
I ever devoloped an exporter for displaying some other data to prometheus. it is only pull data per 5 seconds.
But this time I need write all of data to promethues.  Is there a way to write data to promethues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to load "historical" data like this. You could use the node_exporter's [textfile collector](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector) to setup/scrape your own metrics however you want. However I think that is a bad idea in this case because you will not have timestamps, and my understanding of your question is that you want to load nginx metrics from before you had any prometheus instrumentation setup, so you probably care about when the http_duration was X

For nginx, use the [nginx released exporter](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter#nginx-prometheus-exporter). To use this, you need to add a location directive to your nginx.conf file to setting `stub_status   on;` then point the exporter to the endpoint that you have configured.